# How to make an animation in which an image plane appears with a clockwise motion, like a pie chart

Tags: animation, image, screw-modifier

I want to make an image plane appear with the following animation:

1. image plane is invisible
2. a pie slice of the plane becomes visible
3. The pie slice increases so as to reveal more and more of the image plane in a clockwise (or anticlockwise) motion
4. image plane is completely visible

Trying to come up with a clue I toyed around with the screw modifier, which does offer the animation I want, but then any image texture I apply to it is majorly deformed. I'd want to see the image as is.

How can this be done in Blender? Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

Answer (score 7):

Edit the material so you can animate a radial texture to drive the transparency. Set the Gradient to Radial for a clock wipe effect. Use a math node set to Snap to step through the reveal in segments instead of a continuous wipe.

Notice that in Eevee you must set the material's alpha type to blend or hashed.

[image: Wipe with radial texture]

Comment: Went with this solution in the end, because I could do the animation within a single object. Thanks for the answers! Learnt a lot from both

Answer (score 4):

You could create a simple edge, give it a *Screw* modifier, and enable the *Visibility > Holdout* option so that it create a transparent mask in front of your image. Then enable the *Render > Film > Transparent* option:

[image]